# How do I hide application icon programmatically from react-native

Tags: react-native, icons

EXPO SDK Version 44:
Platforms : ALL

I have been trying to figure out a way I can hide my application Icon programmatically from react-native. I would appreciate if there is any help or resource from the anyone.

THANKS.

Comment: Like, you don't want it to show up on the phone's home screen? A hidden app, for something like spyware?

Comment: Yes @ceejayoz exactly!

Comment: In that case, it is thankfully not possible.